# Eclipse Plugin installation from command line in Linux

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a failure during the install of eclipse plugin in linux using 
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html

In eclipse for Windows I can find the file eclipsec, but it is not found for linux.

Also, When I use eclipse instead of eclipsec in linux I get the error that the installable unit has not been found , and it is there and the same command works for windows

Comment: Could you please update your question with your command line on linux and the error it outputs, since that seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used eclipse instead of eclipsec and it's been installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is dead. You should however be able to put the plugin jar files directly under the dropins folder in your Eclipse folder.

Comment: I use this command  in windows and linux 

`d:\builder\eclipsec.exe
   -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
   -repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5
   -installIU org.eclipse.sdk.ide
   -destination d:/eclipse/
   -profile SDKProfile
   -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true
   -bundlepool d:/eclipse/
   -p2.os linux
   -p2.ws gtk
   -p2.arch x86
   -roaming`